As a Dutch citizen, what are my options to bring my parents out of war?
I am a Syrian / Dutch citizen. I came to the Netherlands 10 years ago to work on a highly skilled immigrant visa, and after 5 years I got the Dutch nationality through naturalization process. Throughout the years, I work, pay all my taxes. My family in Syria are in a dangerous situation now. I would like to bring them here. What are my options?
Notes:

I have a very highly paid job, I will take care of them financially, medically, and for everything.
I own a big house so they can live with me.
I was never ever a refugee, and I am ready to give any proof needed that my family will live with me and never become refugees.
My parents are old (72 and 61)

I really need your help, I am open for all ideas. For example, can I apply for a family reunited visa?
any help would be highly appreciated, the mental stress I am going through is too much already.

are you aware that your parents also can benefit from freedom of movement in the EU? read here: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/family-residence-rights/parents/index_en.htm

@Dr.Snoopy Only under limited circumstances, though.

"I was never ever a refugee, and I am ready to give any proof needed that my family will live with me and never become refugees": To be honest, obtaining asylum in the Netherlands seems to be the only straightforward ready for them to come, as is seems that there is no residence permit for dependent parents.  See https://ind.nl/en/residency-in-the-netherlands. As noted by @Dr.Snoopy, you could bring them to live with you in any other EU country as long as you can prove that they are dependent on you.

@Relaxed its the best option actually, other ways might require approval from the Dutch government, but freedom of movement would be much easier.

@Dr.Snoopy it's only the best option if Sati elshebani is willing to move to a different EU country.

@phoog Well asylum is the other option, and that is much more difficult than moving to another EU country. And I think there is some time urgency implicit in the question due to what is currently happening in Syria.

@Dr.Snoopy It's a great option if you can qualify, which is not particularly easy. It will also require a visa for them, which takes time and effort. And that's without taking into account all that's involved for the OP to move to another country when he has a job and a mortgage in the Netherlands. I don't have anything better to offer than this or asylum but I am weary of giving the OP false hopes.

@Sati_elshebani You cannot prove your parents won't be refugees, they objectively are or would be (or at least deserving of subsidiary protection), even if they do not seek to have their status recognized. If they do make it to the Netherlands, there is really no reason they shouldn't.

@Relaxed The question literally says open to all options, let the OP decide on the options.

@Dr.Snoopy Yes, of course, but you wrote that the parents could benefit from freedom of movement as if it was a done deal and covered the parents of every EU citizens. I am adding that this is only true under very limited circumstances: moving to another EU country, showing you have work and sufficient resources to live there, proving they are dependent on you and once you have done all this, they will still need to find a consulate they can access and wait for a visa.

@Relaxed Sure, but that is probably faster than trying to get an asylum application approved in the Netherlands. And depending on the situation, it might be the only option.

@Dr.Snoopy Yes but that's time waiting in Syria or any other place they might reach but there aren't many options. And there is no alternative between this and an asylum application as the latter requires being in the Netherlands already. The processing time happens after you have reached the country, the real problem is getting there.

I'm unfamiliar with Dutch specifics, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer. You have basically two options: normal immigration as dependants of you, and application for refugee status, with you as sponsor and guarantor. Neither is going to happen immediately.

The situation you outline is complex, and not likely to get easier any time soon. If I were you (given that you say you have a highly paid job so professional fees should not be a problem), I would get advice from a Dutch Immigration lawyer. Better than a bunch of opinions from internet strangers, no matter how well-informed they might be.
